# How to Access User's Preferences That are Saved as Boolean Field in Django Models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to add preferences to user accounts. Each preference is true/false value and it needs to stay this way.

Since each account might have multiple preferences I would like to know how to loop through them in my templates and have those preferences easily available throughout the app.

Ex. I want to display user's name and all of the colors they like.

models.py

```
class UserColors(models.Model):
    white = models.BooleanField(_("White"))
    black = models.BooleanField(_("Black"))

class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, verbose_name='user', related_name='account')
    colors = models.ForeignKey('UserColors', null=True)
```

views.py

```
class UserView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'account'
    template_name = 'detail.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```

template.html

```
user: {% account.user.username %} <br>
colors: 

# the following would be ideal instead of doing multiple ifs in search for true/false values
{% for color in account.colors %}
    color.name
{% endif %}
```

output

```
user: userName
colors: white, black
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

In my original answer, I tried restructuring the data and keeping the values as boolean.  It looks like we need to stay closer to the original structure.

You can loop through the fields on your `UserColors` model.  It's easier in the View code, as you need getattr:

```
def get_context_data(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = super(UserView, self).get_context_data(request, *args, **kwargs)
    acct = data['account'] # Guessing this is here based on your posted template code
    colors = {}
    for field in acct.colors._meta.fields:
        colors[field.name] = getattr(acct.colors, field.name, False)
    data['usercolors'] = colors
    return data
```

Then in the template:

```
{% for k,v in usercolors.items() %}
   {% if v %}
   {{ k }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Original answer:**

You could structure it like this:

```
class UserColor(models.Model):
    colors = {
        "WHITE": "WHT",
        "BLACK": "BLK",
    }

    color_choices = (
        (colors['WHITE'], "White"),
        (colors['BLACK'], "Black"),
    )

    name = models.CharField(_("Color Name"), max_length=3, choices=color_choices)
    value = models.BooleanField(_("Whether they like it"))
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Then point one at each user for each color that you want to specify:

```
user = User.objects.get(name="me")
white = UserColor.objects.create(
    color=UserColor.colors['WHITE'], value=False, user=user)
black = UserColor.objects.create(
    color=UserColor.colors['BLACK'], value=True, user=user)
```

Use it like this:

```
{% for color in user.color_set.all() %}
  {{ color.name }}: {{ color.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I like your suggestion but as I mentioned in my question I have to keep the colors as boolean fields.